# Windows Store apps verticalization / customization

Tags: windows-store-apps, customization, windows-8.1, windows-store

The issue is the following: I have developed an app which has to be tailored to multiple customers (actually, just string/color/UI-related resources need to be customized). It should also be noted that other customizations may be implemented on the webservice-side.
The result of such an operation has to be a new app (with a new name) to be submitted to the store.

Is this contemplated by Windows Store policies?

What approaches can I follow?

A first approach which comes to my mind is straightforward but error-prone and verbose:
creating an app which performs the following operations:

1. Makes a copy of the solution
2. Retrieves all the solution resources
3. Allows the user to customize the resources
4. Builds in output the new app version (solution) with the overrides

Answer (score 0):

If the "user" that will do the customization is a developer, meaning someone who knows how to use Visual Studio, I'd suggest creating a Visual Studio template project.

You can easily export your existing app project as template (Microsoft provides a basic step-by-step explanation at [How to: Create Project Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xkh1wxd8.aspx), and I've once written a blog post that contains a more detailed tutorial: [Creating template projects](http://www.mobilemotion.eu/?p=736)).

Either way, the result is a .VSIX file that can be installed as Visual Studio Add-In. With that, any developer that has the project template installed can choose it from the File -> New -> Project... dialog in Visual Studio - a new project will be created including all the files from the original project, the developer can then adapt the resource files and build the project into a new App.